# Chamando funções no ngClass

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, classes

Gostaria de chamar funções no ngClass. consegui chamar apenas a função, e se quero chamar outras classes ele não pega, seu eu colocar apenas a função no class ele consegue chamar(ng-class="styleClass(5)"), mas eu quero que algumas classes sempre estejam e outras possam ser alteradas por outras validações. Quando eu tiro a função do exemplo, ele funciona tudo certo.

Segue o Exemplo:

JavaScript

```
$scope.styleClass = function(i) {
  console.log("entrou");
  if(i>1){
      return 'bg';
  }
  return ''
}
```

HTML

```
First Name: <input type="text" ng-class="{'text':true, 'padd':true, 'styleClass(5)':true}" ng-model="firstName"><br>
```

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversei com uns amigos e descobri um jeito, que é

```
ng-class="[styleClass(5),{'text': true, 'padd': true}]"
```

Comment: Provavelmente deve funcionar dessa forma também `ng-class="[styleClass(5), 'text', 'padd']"`

Comment: sim, funciona mas assim não da pra colocar condicionais se necessário

Answer (score 0):

Você pode misturar o atributo `class` (com as classes fixas) com o `ng-class` para retorno da função:

```
<input type="text" class="text padd" ng-class="styleClass(5)" ng-model="firstName">
```

Comment: é que eu tenho que fazer outras validações de outras classes no ng-class

Comment: conversei cm uns amigos meus e descobri um jeito, que é ng-class="[styleClass(5),{'text': true, 'padd': true}]"

Comment: @EduardoBobato se quiser pode inserir isso como outra resposta